# NameError: name 'blocks' is not defined

Tags: python, python-turtle

As said in the title, I keep getting a `NameError` that states blocks is not defined, even though I have created a blocks instance with `blocks = Blocks()`

```py
def setup_maze(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            character = level[y][x]
            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            # Check if it is an X representing a wall
            if character == "X":
                blocks.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                blocks.stamp()

                # Add coordinates to wall list
                walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))

            if character == "P":
                player.goto(screen_x, screen_y)

            if character == "T":
                treasures.append(Treasure(screen_x, screen_y))

            # Check if it is E representing enemies
            if character == "E":
                enemies.append(Enemy(screen_x, screen_y))

            # Check if it is G representing gate
            if character == "G":
                gates.append(Gate(screen_x, screen_y))

     # Creating class instance
        blocks = Blocks()
        player = Player()
```

Comment: First of all fix your indentations. Also where are you defining Blocks and Players?

Comment: @coderman1234 this is not important here

Comment: @drum not important here ...

Comment: Wait, are you calling the setup function after the definition of blocks, or before it?

Comment: Also, I would pass in the object `blocks` that you made as an argument to the `setup_maze` function, so you don't have to deal with things like this.

Comment: @coderman1234 I call the setup function after

Answer (score 1):

Indentation error!

```
def setup_maze(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            character = level[y][x]
            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            # Check if it is an X representing a wall
            if character == "X":
                blocks.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                blocks.stamp()
    
                # Add coordinates to wall list
                walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))

            if character == "P":
                player.goto(screen_x, screen_y)

            if character == "T":
                treasures.append(Treasure(screen_x, screen_y))

            # Check if it is E representing enemies
            if character == "E":
                enemies.append(Enemy(screen_x, screen_y))

            # Check if it is G representing gate
            if character == "G":
                gates.append(Gate(screen_x, screen_y))



# Creating class instance
blocks = Blocks()
player = Player()
setup_maze(2)  # call function; passing blocks and players is recommended instead of using global variables
```

Comment: Not the issue, messed up my indentation when pasting my code

Comment: then please post a minimum reproducible error; post the stack trace and a simplified version of the code which still has the issue and we can repeat (e.g. giving a simplified implementation of blocks)